# Is the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Is the ring $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ a local ring? That is, the set of non-units an ideal of the ring?

I think yes, because the only prime that divides the order of the ring is $p$, so the number of maximal ideals is also $1$. Any hints? Thanks beforehand

Comment: The non-units are the multiples of $p$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux so, that means, the only ideal is $\langle p\rangle$, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi Your reasoning (“because only one prime divides its order”) is insufficient.  On one hand it is a false deduction in general. On the other hand it is true for quotients of Z, but it is precisely what you are trying to prove , so it would be circular logic to appeal to it.

Comment: Maximum ideal $\langle p\rangle$, unique.

Comment: @rschwieb ok, so finally the ring is local, right? And, by the way, can use the argument that $Z_n$ is dedekind?  Or, the argument that the only prime that is non-coprime to $p^n$ is $p$?Because Iread somewhere that the maximal ideals of the ring of integers modulo $n$ are precisely those generated by primes non-coprime to $n$

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, the ring is local.  I'm not really sure what "Dedekind" means for something that isn't a domain.  The argument about the nonunits being an ideal is the most straightforward, IMO.

Comment: You could also use an ideal correspondence argument, where the maximal (resp. prime) ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ are the images under the quotient map of the maximal (resp. prime) ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contain the ideal $(p^n)$, and then show that there is only one such ideal (you probably already know about the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $R/M^k$ is a local ring.

*Hint:* The maximal ideals of $R/M^k$ correspond with the maximal ideals of $R$ containing $M^k$.  Suppose $P$ is such an ideal (keeping in mind that maximal ideals are prime!) What does $M^k\subseteq P$ imply?

Comment: so this is somewhat like the correspondence theorem for groups, isnt it

Comment: There is a correspondence theorem for groups, rings, modules etc, yes.